# Looking to compile a list of songs about ghosts

Tags: playlists

I'm trying to put together a list of songs where ghosts - either metaphorical or literal - figure prominently. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first one that comes to mind is "My Wife and My Dead Wife" by Robyn Hitchcock.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you're looking for a particular genre, but old traditional folk ballads have some ghost-related songs.

1. La Llorona: here's [a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Llorona_(song)) to a Wikipedia article about it, with lyrics. There are many versions but this one with Jazmin Lopez is one of my favorites.

2. The Long Black Veil is also a traditional ghost-related song. The Chieftains did a nice version with Mick Jagger on vocals.

3. The House Carpenter (also called The Daemon Lover) is an old traditional with many versions. I like this one by Myrkur. [Link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daemon_Lover) w/more info.

4. Sweet William's Ghost (sometimes called Lady Margaret); [info](https://mainlynorfolk.info/louis.killen/songs/sweetwilliamsghost.html) on English folk music site Mainly Norfolk. You might find some others there if you search for Child Ballads. Also info on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_William%27s_Ghost).

5. Anna von Hausswolff has several that would fit. Funeral For My Future Children is one, and you can find more on YouTube. Hope you like these :)

Answer (score 1):

*Graceful Ghost Rag* - William Bolcom

*The Ghost Inside* - Broken Bells

*Ghostbusters Theme* - Roy Parker Jr.

*The Ghost of Tom Joad* - Bruce Springsteen

*Jenny, Again* - Tuung

*Zombie Jamboree* - King Flash

*I Come and Stand At Every Door* - Anne Hills

*The Unquiet Grave* (folk song)

*I am Stretched on Your Grave* - Sinead O'Connor

*Helena* - My Chemical Romance

*Never Catch Me* - Flying Lotus/ Kendrick Lamar

*Thugz Mansion* - 2Pac

*I'll Be There* - Escape Club

Answer (score 1):

"[With Her Head Tucked Underneath Her Arm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1YGaVjhjG0)" (1934), lyrics by R. P. Weston and Bert Lee, music by Harris Weston

"[Casper the Friendly Ghost Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljeg8pABKyI)", by Mack David and Jerry Livingston

"[The New Casper Cartoon Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVlJ5cHvNEY)" (Opening and Closing themes)

"[The Headless Horseman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysNSKrH8hHo)", from Disney's *The Adventures of Ichabod and Mr. Toad (1949) – The Legend of Sleepy Hollow*, by Don Raye and Gene de Paul

"[Commentadore Scene](https://youtu.be/jATcM8X29zc)" fron *Don Giovanni*, by Mozart

Peter Quint and Mrs. Jessel from Benjamin Britten's *[The Turn of The Screw](https://youtu.be/AqJw63OqDrI)*

"[The Flying Dutchman](https://youtu.be/u5hc9HNPay4)" (1843), by Richard Wagner (The entire opera is about a ghost.)

Answer (score 0):

"Ghosts", by Japan...?